# Revoke connect from superuser

Tags: security, postgresql, roles, privileges

Is there any way to revoke connect (or preferably all) privileges on database from role that is defined as superuser on the server? On dev server we've got several databases - one of them is shared, but the rest should be owned only by one developer without connect permission for others. Currently all developers are superusers with login option.

```
CREATE ROLE dev_name LOGIN
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '...'
  SUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION;
```

I've tried to do this on many ways:

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE test_db FROM dev_name;
revoke select on all tables in schema public from dev_name;
```

and then as I checked with:

```
SELECT * FROM has_database_privilege('dev_name', 'test_db', 'connect');
```

still returned true.

I've tried with workaround and changed connection limit to another value, but still superusers could connect even when I first logged in:

```
 CONNECTION LIMIT = 1;
```

So, maybe is there chance to do this without messing with pg_hba or dropping superuser status for other developers?

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll need to remove superuser status from these developers.

Relevant quotes from the manual:

- [Accessing a Database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-accessdb.html)

  > Being a superuser means that you are not subject to access controls
- [CREATE ROLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html)

> These clauses determine whether the new role is a "superuser", who can
>   override all access restrictions within the database

Comment: Note however that you are NOT immune to access control in the pg_hba.conf file.  But it looks like OP is abusing super user somehow.